# UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER) Object is currently in trigger therefore it cannot recursively update itself

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

I have two objects Account & Patient. Patient having look up relationship with Account.
(One to one relationship)
Some fields are common in both.
In my case user can update those fields from both object.
I have written trigger to update account fields on Patient object.
And process builder to update patient fields on Account Object.
When I am trying to update patient record I am getting this error:

> Error Occurred: UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS :
>   (SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER) Object (id = a0cO000000CfogI) is
>   currently in trigger LockRecord, therefore it cannot recursively
>   update itself,

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code. According to the error, you are trying to perform DML operation on the same **record** which also exist in `Trigger.New` or `Trigger.Old`.

Make sure that you are not updating the same record which is part of `Trigger.New` List.